# Reading zip file from byte array using Ionic.zip

Tags: c#, ionic-framework, zip

I have a piece of code that allows to decompress a byte array:

```
public static byte[] Decompress(this byte[] data)
{
    using (ZipFile zout = ZipFile.Read(data))
    {
        ZipEntry entry = zout.FirstOrDefault();
        Assert.ObjectIsNotNull(entry, "Unable to find default ZIP entry");
        MemoryStream zos = new MemoryStream();
        entry.Extract(zos);
        return zos.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I upgraded to the latest version of Ionic.zip and now I am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert byte[] to string.

The overload `ZipFile.Read(byte[])` is no longer available in the most recent version.

How can I read a zip file from a byte array?

Comment: ZipFile.Read() takes the filename as a parameter, not a byte[].

Comment: I am asking for help because not able to figure out how to resolve the issue.  what benefit is downvoting without providing any help?

Comment: I upvoted you. Focus on the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks. I never downvoted in the first place, just wanted to show him that I was trying to help and not downvoting. You're right though, upvote removed :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ZipFile.Read` method takes either a filename or a stream to read, so you need to provide a stream for it to read:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
using (ZipFile zout = ZipFile.Read(stream))
{
    // ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `ZipArchive` class in `System.IO.Commpression`.

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    using(var archive = new ZipArchive(stream))
    {
        // Use the archive
    }
 }
```

`ZipArchive`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158268(v=vs.110).aspx

`MemoryStream`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx

You will need to add a reference to `System.IO.Compression`, it is not in `mscorlib`.